# How to save data into 2 tables

Tags: .net, angular

I need to save my question module into two tables. first one is question and second one is question answer table. question table contains questionId,question category from category table,question type from question type table, question weightage, question description. In the question table there is questionanswerId, question id, typeId, options ,points. I need to store these thimgs from one form. I'm using .net web api for backend and angular for front end. Can you please help me to do this?

i need save these data into two tables using .net and angular

I need to save my data into 2 tables from one form using .net amd angular

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it, depending on where you want to draw the separation line. At some point the command to add a question and a question answer are going to need to be 2 separate commands. It looks like you are sending the question and answer to the server in a single API call already. If you want to keep that approach, you just need to add the question and the answer to the database separately. You may need to create a new object which has a `question` property and a `answer` property, and accept that in your `AddQuestion` action since getting the data binder to work with separate parameters can be difficult in .net (I'm not sure which version you are using). Once the data gets to the .net server, it shouldn't be too hard to make separate database calls to add all the items to their various tables.

Another solution would be to have a separate controller action for adding an answer. This would require Angular/Typescript to split up the form, after submitting, into the question part and the answer part, then call the appropriate controller action with the correct data. You would probably need to submit the question first, then wait for the reply from the .net web server to get the question's id to add to the answer so they can be associated. This would also require you to split your stored procedure into 2 procedures, one for questions, one for answers.